# JMeter: Record n play, also gives API access

Tags: api, rest, jmeter

I have recorded a login flow of an application and found some URIs like below:

1. /api/oauth2/initiate `GET`
2. /oauth2/authorize `GET`
3. /api/v1/oauth2/authorize `GET`
4. /api/v1/oauth2/authenticate `POST`

   - `{"username":"${Username}","password":"${Password}","client_id":"${client_Id}","response_type":"code","redirect_uri":"${scheme}://${host}/api/oauth2/callback","server_id":"${server_Id}"}`

When I am hitting above in sequence via JMeter I am getting `200` response. Just like JMeter I tried recording in Postman and it worked same, but instead of JSON it gave response in `XML` format.

It doesn't generate a `access_token`, it works via session cookies.

My question is - Do I really have API access or it is just browser record n play? If Yes, Does this mean I can get access to any API, if I am a registered user of that application? For ex: Facebook, YouTube or any startup website.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter works on the protocol level. This means that whatever request you are generating. Say a simple browser request or an API call, you can do that easily.
Now the thing is replicating requests. You don't need to record the requests necessarily using the browser. You need to analyze the few things that are required. Say Postman is generating a request. You specify the things you want to send and you use the API Token there. The same things can be specified there as well. It all depends on how you are understanding the concept of request generation.

You simply need to replicate the samplers and the parameters. And the request headers in postman can be replicated here in the same way.
For each HTTP Request Sampler make sure you add a corresponding child HTTP Header Manager config element.

Headers basically tell the server that what client we are using and in what form data is being sent and then server responds accordingly with the information.

Answer (score 0):

What you're recorded is [OAuth2](https://oauth.net/2/) flow and you won't be able to replay it without [correlating](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-1-correlations) the dynamic values.

You can have access to [Google API](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer) or [Facebook Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api) given you have proper `access_token` but I don't think you should be testing them directly, you should focus on solely your application.

Comment: I am not going to Test Facebook or Google :). Let me rephrase my question - Our Client has only asked to test their website. I register, create username, password access the website, use more other features. Later I do same with JMeter. Now what JMeter has exposed to me, does that mean I really have access to their APIs? If Yes, then anyone who registers on website has API access which seems security issue.